# Bitmap, как определить вес изображения до сохранения на жесткий диск?

Tags: c#

У нас есть два изображения, одно после сохранения из памяти на диск занимает 3 Мб, другое 2 Мб.

Как получить вес (размер) изображения в мегабайтах до сохранения?

Comment: Может хоть код покажите, какой bitmap у Вас используется? А вообще всё зависит от степени сжатия. Если без сжатия, то посчитать достаточно просто. Если со сжатием то, полагаю, никак.

Comment: @ixSci, я имел ввиду общий алгоритм действий при подобной задаче. Я не имел ввиду конкретный формат или степень сжатия. Может быть есть какие то штатные средства или готовые классы\библиотеки?

Comment: @ixSci, ну или просто приведите простой пример на любом формате, который вам удобен.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуем разобраться с получением размера, на примере [System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx). На мой взгляд можно выделить 2 случая:

1. Мы хотим узнать размер выходного файла в сыром(raw) виде
2. Мы хотим узнать размер выходного файла в сжатом виде.

Первый способ довольно прост, и мы имеем все данные в самом объекте, чтобы посчитать размер. Итак, размер результирующего файла будет следующим:

```
Размер = Высота*Ширина*КоличествоБайтНаКаждыйПиксель
```

Где `Высота` это `Bitmap.Height`, `Ширина` это `Bitmap.Width`, а `КоличествоБайтНаКаждыйПиксель` может быть получено из свойства [Bitmap.PixelFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.image.pixelformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

Совсем другое дело, когда мы используем какое-либо сжатие(JPEG, PNG и т.д). Тут мы уже просто посчитать не можем. Поэтому пойдём другим путём. Воспользуемся методом `Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat)` и запишем наш файл в `System.IO.MemoryStream`, размер которого будет содержаться в свойстве `Length`.

Comment: ох, не всё так просто для Bitmap. Предложенный вариант, к сожалению не сработает: там ещё плюс заголовки, плюс палитра, минус RLE-сжатие(да, оно сжимается, хоть и не сильно) ))

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, какое сжатие? Я говорил о тупом дампе "пикселей" в файл. Да, было бы неплохо туда ещё добавить windth/height/pixel format, для последующего считывания. Но это все максимум 12 байт, что роли не играет, в общей картине.

Comment: А.. ясно. Я просто думал о сохранении Bitmap в BMP, через метод Save(). Если просто сериализовать пиксели, то да - так посчитать получится.

Answer (score 3):

Подгонка размера изображения и качества сжатия под желаемый объём на диске: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=43424

Вот код оттуда (надо бы ещё using'и к stream'ам добавить):

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Module All

Public Function GetJpegContent(ByVal Pct As Image) As Byte()
  Dim File As New MemoryStream
  Pct.Save(File, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
  Return File.ToArray()
End Function

Public Function GetJpegContent(ByVal Pct As Image, ByVal Quality As Long) As Byte()
  Dim File As New MemoryStream
  Dim EncoderParams As New EncoderParameters(1)
  EncoderParams.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, Quality)
  Pct.Save(File, GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg"), EncoderParams)
  Return File.ToArray()
End Function

Private Function GetEncoderInfo(ByVal MimeType As String) As ImageCodecInfo
  For Each Codec As ImageCodecInfo In ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
    If Codec.MimeType = MimeType Then Return Codec
  Next Codec
  Return Nothing
End Function

Public Function ReduceByQuality(ByVal Pct As Image, ByVal Lim As Integer) As Byte()
  Dim LastOk() As Byte = Nothing, Res() As Byte
  Dim L As Integer = 0, R As Integer = 100, Cur As Integer

  Do While L < R
    Cur = (L + R + 1) >> 1
    Res = GetJpegContent(Pct, Cur)
    If Res.Length > Lim Then
      R = Cur - 1
    Else
      L = Cur
      LastOk = Res
    End If
  Loop

  Return LastOk
End Function

Public Function ReduceBySize(ByVal Pct As Image, ByVal Lim As Integer) As Byte()
  Dim LastOk() As Byte = Nothing, Res() As Byte
  Dim LHeight As Integer = 0, RHeight As Integer = Pct.Height, CurHeight As Integer
  Dim LWidth As Integer = 0, RWidth As Integer = Pct.Width, CurWidth As Integer

  Do While LHeight < RHeight
    CurHeight = (LHeight + RHeight + 1) >> 1
    CurWidth = (LWidth + RWidth + 1) >> 1
    Res = GetJpegContent(New System.Drawing.Bitmap(CType(Pct, Bitmap), CurWidth, CurHeight))
    If Res.Length > Lim Then
      RHeight = CurHeight - 1
      RWidth = CurWidth - 1
    Else
      LHeight = CurHeight
      LWidth = CurWidth
      LastOk = Res
    End If
  Loop

  Return LastOk
End Function

Public Sub Main()
  My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("ReduceByQuality.jpg", ReduceByQuality(Bitmap.FromFile("input.jpg"), 307200), False)
  My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("ReduceBySize.jpg", ReduceBySize(Bitmap.FromFile("input.jpg"), 307200), False)
  MsgBox("Ready")
End Sub

End Module
```

То же самое на C#:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public static class All
{
    public static byte[] GetJpegContent(Image pct)
    {
        using (var file = new MemoryStream())
        {
            pct.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return file.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] GetJpegContent(Image pct, long quality)
    {
        using (var file = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
            pct.Save(file, GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg"), EncoderParams);
            return file.ToArray();
        }
    }

    static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
                             .FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.MimeType == mimeType);
    }

    public byte[] ReduceByQuality(Image pct, int lim)
    {
        byte[] laskOK = null;
        byte[] res;

        int l = 0, r = 100, cur;
        while (l < r)
        {
            cur = (L + R + 1) / 2;
            res = GetJpegContent(pct, cur);
            if (res.Length > lim)
            {
                r = cur - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                l = cur;
                lastOk = res;
            }
        }
        return lastOk;
    }

    public byte[] ReduceBySize(Image pct, int lim)
    {
        byte[] lastOk = null;
        byte[] res;

        int lHeight = 0, rHeight = pct.Height, curHeight;
        int lWidth = 0, rWidth = Pct.Width, curWidth;

        while (lHeight < rHeight)
        {
            curHeight = (lHeight + rHeight + 1) / 2;
            curWidth = (lWidth + rWidth + 1) / 2;
            res = GetJpegContent(
                      new System.Drawing.Bitmap((Bitmap)pct, cCurWidth, curHeight));
            if (res.Length > lim)
            {
                rHeight = curHeight - 1;
                rWidth = curWidth - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                lHeight = curHeight;
                lWidth = curWidth;
                lastOk = res;
            }
        }

        return lastOk;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static Main()
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(
            "ReduceByQuality.jpg",
            All.ReduceByQuality(Bitmap.FromFile("input.jpg"), 307200),
            false);
        File.WriteAllBytes(
            "ReduceBySize.jpg",
            All.ReduceBySize(Bitmap.FromFile("input.jpg"), 307200),
            false);
    }
}
```

Comment: бинарный поиск с упаковкой в jpeg на каждом шаге? о_О

Comment: @VladD, а как бы ты это сделал?

Comment: вы/ты не против, если я перекодирую в C# (прямо в этом ответе)?

Comment: @VladD, подожди. Я кажется код с багом скопировал. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @VladD, заменил код. Против конвертирования на C# не возражаю, если 1. останется код на обоих языках, 2. код на C# нормально написанный, а не результат применения конвертера с кучей сомнительных операций. А ещё в нём недостаток, что не расставлены using'и на bitmap'ы и stream'ы.

Comment: Не, ну тоже идея, конечно. Непонятно как обрабатывать проблему, если ухудшение качества меняет размер файла так, что изменение больше заданной точности.

Comment: Окей, сейчас добавлю. Никакого конвертера, всё руками.

Comment: Можно и конвертером сначала - главное причесать его не забыть :)